# DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode is not triggered in the Visual Studio Extension Package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

I wrote a visual studio extension package that subscribes to DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode event. But this event is never get raised.

Here is some code:

```
protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        applicationObject = (DTE2) GetService(typeof (DTE));

        applicationObject.Events.BuildEvents.OnBuildDone += BuildEventsOnOnBuildDone;
        applicationObject.Events.DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode += DebuggerEventsOnOnEnterBreakMode;
    }
```

But method `DebuggerEventsOnOnEnterBreakMode` is never called. Method `BuildEventsOnOnBuildDone` is called.

Why this can happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this sounds silly but in order to listen to the `DebuggerEvents` events you need to maintain a reference to `DebuggerEvent`s itself.

```
DebuggerEvents _debuggerEvents;

protected override void Initialize() {
  applicationObject = (DTE2) GetService(typeof (DTE));

  _debuggerEvents = applicationObject.Events.DebuggerEvents;
  _debuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode += DebuggerEventsOnOnEnterBreakMode
```

The reason for this is subtle.  `DebuggerEvents` is actually a COM / CCW object which is created on demand when the `DTE.DebuggerEvents` property is accessed.  The event handler code doesn't keep the CCW alive hence the next GC potentially collects the `DebuggerEvents` property and takes the event handler with it.

It's a really strange bug that is specific to CCW and events.  I've heard it referred to as "the most vexing bug ever" and it's not far from the truth

Comment: I think the vexing part is that Events.DebuggerEvents isn't a singleton -- that's how it would normally be implemented in pure managed code.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day (or even week) :)